# React native onScroll ScrollView user event vs animation event

Tags: react-native, touch, scrollview

How can i can detect onScroll ScrollView event from a user vs an animation

in React  Native the "onScroll" event is returned when a user makes a move and also when I move it using code

Comment: You need to show some code in order to see the cause of the other event from this other "animation".